# scrape element not visible in page source

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website (`https://harleytherapy.com/therapists?page=1`) that looks like it's been generated by Javascript and the element I'm trying to scrape (the `lu` with `id="downshift-7-menu"`) doesn't appear on the "Page source" but only after I click on "Inspect element".

I tried to find a solution here and so far this the code I was able to come up with (a combination of Selenium + Beautiful soup)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
import time

url = "https://harleytherapy.com/therapists?page=1"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
capa = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
capa["pageLoadStrategy"] = "none"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, desired_capabilities=capa)
driver.set_window_size(1440,900)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(15)

plain_text = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html')
therapist_menu_id = "downshift-7-menu"
print(soup.find(id=therapist_menu_id))
```

I thought that allowing Selenium to wait for 15 seconds would make sure that all elements are loaded but I still can't find any element with id `downshift-7-menu` in the soup. Do you guys know what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element with ID `downshift-7-menu` is loaded only after opening the THERAPIST dropdown menu, you can do it by scrolling it into view to load it and then clicking on it. You should also consider replacing sleep with explicit wait

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

# scroll the dropdown into view to load it
side_menu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'inner-a377b5')))
last_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", side_menu)
while True:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTo(0, arguments[0].scrollHeight);", side_menu)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollHeight", side_menu)
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

# open the menu
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'downshift-7-input'))).click()

# wait for the option to load
therapist_menu_id = 'downshift-7-menu'
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, therapist_menu_id)))
print(soup.find(id=therapist_menu_id))
```

Comment: thanks! this works but only after I wait for Selenium to open the website and manually click on the Therapist dropdown menu. Is there a way to skip the manual step?

Comment: @Brian I edited my answer, scroll to the dropdown first to make it visible